# Replace round brackets in MySQL

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a `table` with `column` `productname`.

Product name may contain round brackets.

My question is how I can `replace` round brackets while searching inside a query.

Let say product name is "kitkat(100gm)" and if the user searches for kitkat100, it should display "kitkat(100gm)"

My query is

```
Select * from products 
where REPLACE(productname, '(', '') like REPLACE('%kitkat100%', '(', '')
```

Even if I use back-slash then too getting the same error.

```
Select * from products 
    where REPLACE(productname, '\(', '') like REPLACE('%kitkat100%', '\(', '')
```

But this is giving me error

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
 'LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

How I can resolve this?

Comment: you can have an extra column that stores values without parentheses. so if you find a result based on search keyword you can return original column value.

Comment: @Badiparmagi actually the database is already in use with 1000s of products in it, hence it is not so feasible now.

Comment: how about creating a view that has an extra column without parentheses?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Replace Character in Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734077/mysql-replace-character-in-columns)

Comment: @RobertH tried the solution provided but no luck.

Answer (score -1):

You're pretty close, but you don't have to include the replace in the 'LIKE' clause.  i.e.

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE REPLACE(productname, '(', '') LIKE '%kitkat100%'
```

Comment: @abbas That query (And even yours for that matter) should be working correctly. Can you post the full MySQL error, as well as the code you're using to execute it?

Comment: @FrankerZ, I have edited my question with complete error.

Comment: @abbas At no point in your queries did you mention a LIMIT. We need the full code you're using to connect to the DB.

Comment: @FrankerZ, yes this is the complete query and the complete error, correct I didn't mention limit but then too it is giving the said error.

Comment: Seems to be similar to this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35798826/mysql-error-in-your-sql-syntax-limit-0-25

Where the problem was indeed a missing close bracket.  Not sure quite why the SQL engine is interpreting it that way though.